# Showing and Hiding input fields

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to make a form that is right under a table row. I know I don't have the form formatted correctly but I am trying to tackle multiple issues at once. I am very new to angular I only did the tour of heroes once. And I need to build a java back-end and Angular front-end so please be mindful of that. I want to display my one form when I click on my edit but All the form pops up. **I can not link stackblitz because it won't allow me for some reason I did try to. If you have any questions on what I want to do let me know. The first answer given does not answer my question so please submit more.**

```
home.component.html

 <div class="table-responsive">
        <table  class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>FullPrice <i id ="asc-desc1"class="fas fa-angle-down" (click)="SortPrice($event)"></i></th>
            <th>Saleprice <i id ="asc-desc2"class="fas fa-angle-down" (click)="SortSale($event)"></i> </th>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            <th>Discount<i id ="asc-desc3"class="fas fa-angle-down" (click)="SortDiscount($event)"></i></th>
            <th>Edit</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody  *ngFor="let home of home | paginate:{itemsPerPage:20,currentPage: p}" >
          <tr *ngIf="!editMode">
            <td >{{home.id}}</td>
            <td>{{home.productName}}</td>
            <td>{{home.category.categoryName}}</td>
            <td>{{home.fullPrice}}</td>
            <td>{{home.salePrice}}</td>
            <td>{{home.supplier.supplierName}}</td>
            <td>{{home.discount }}</td>
            <td class="text-right" id="tableDataBtns">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button  (click)="editMode=true" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngIf="editMode">
          <td><input placeholder="{{home.id}}"/></td>
          <td><input placeholder="{{home.productName}}"/></td>
          <td><input placeholder="{{home.category.categoryName}}"/></td>
          <td><input placeholder="{{home.fullPrice}}"/></td>
          <td><input placeholder="{{home.salePrice}}"/></td>
          <td><input placeholder="{{home.supplier.supplierName}}"/></td>
          <td><input placeholder="{{home.discount }}"/></td>
          <td class="text-right" id="tableDataBtns">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <button  (click)="editMode=true" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>


          </tbody>
        </table>
        <pagination-controls class="myPagination" (pageChange)="p= $event"></pagination-controls>
      </div>
```

what I want I only want to be able to show and edit one product
[image]
how It looks when I am not in edit mode
[image: When I am not in editmode]
How it looks when I am in editmode all of the forms display I only want one 
[image: This is what happens when I click editmode all of the products are editable I only need one product to be editable]

Comment: Well this should work (for a single line), so could you please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue ?

Comment: You can do it on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: I can't sorry, I had a problem doing that for some reason it wouldn't let me use my repo.

Comment: you can do it by adding class which having display none css use **ngClass**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open one edit at a time, you need to have an unique identifier for each item. You can do it with the help of a boolean variable and the index of the iteration in template. Here is a simplified example of your code, where we use the variable `editMode` that you have, but let's attach the index too:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Category</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
        <ng-container *ngIf="editMode !== i">
            <td>{{item.productName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.categoryName}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <! -- if assigned index to editMode matches -->
        <ng-container *ngIf="editMode === i">
            <td><input [(ngModel)]="item.productName" /></td>
            <td><input [(ngModel)]="item.categoryName" /></td>
        </ng-container>
    <td>
      <!-- Assign the index to edit mode, which item clicked -->
      <button (click)="editMode = i">Edit</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And when you have done the edit, just set `editMode` to `false`.

**[Here's a STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erx2xt?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Yes! This Is exactly What I am looking for thank you helping me.

Comment: You are very welcome, if it helped, please consider accepting the answer. Have a nice weekend and happy coding!

Comment: I do have a question if you don't . How do you toggle? if the 'editMode = i' is the expression how change it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you please rephrase.

Comment: How do I set edit mode to toggle do I use a a function that switches between true and false?

Comment: I still don't really understand. Could you explain the usecase, maybe easier to understand?

Comment: At the end of your comment you said you can just set edit mode to false but how do you toggle between true and false  to show the input field.

Comment: yes, I said that since I don't know how you want it handled. This is one way... when clicked again on button, it will change: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqkywo?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: yes! thanks again :) this is exactly what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a function in your controller which toggles your `editMode` property:

```
editMode: boolean = false;

toogleEditMode() {
  this.editMode = this.editMode ? false : true; 
}
```

And in your template:

```
<button  (click)="toggleEditMode()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>
```

Comment: That's no improvement from his original code, you're just moving it from the template to the controller.

Comment: @Maryannah that's not correct. `editMode` stays true forever, once clicked on the corresponding button.

Comment: Tru, I indeed didn't see that. But a comment to state it would have been best suited ... But since it answers the question, I'm removing my downvote !

Comment: That's all great and all but you didn't answer my now it  has editmode for all my table rows. I am using *ngFor for both table row. I want to be able to only edit one row  when clicked right now it activates edit mode for all my products.

Comment: @matthiasunt  it actually does remain true forever that's why the *ngif condition is !editmode